# Showing there is a cartesian coordinate system in Euclidean geometry.

Tags: geometry, self-learning

I'm pretty sure I should just show there is a bijection between the points in Euclidean Geometry and elements of $\mathbb{R^2}$. How do I do this?

Comment: How do you define Euclidean Geometry to begin with?

Comment: All the goodies from neutral geometry and the parallel postulate? @Fundamental